# ssrs how to select repeat values with different label

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

[image]

as you se in my image,
first I push "(Select All)" then this does not select all items, but it does select all values, how can I select all, I dont mind this select repeat values, but users is seeing non repeat value (label).

working in visual studio 2008

the select return something as it

```
value label
1      a
1      b
1      c
2      d
3      e
4      f
5      g
1      h
```

Comment: How are you generating the list of values?

Comment: you could see it I have edit my question adding a example

Comment: SSRS treats the Values as keys so having duplicates in your list seems pointless. Why would you want to pass the same key when the user thinks they have selected different items? I would rethink the design.

Comment: but is it possible do I want to do or isn't it possible?

Comment: What you are asking doesn't make sense. The values for the parameter should be unique.